# How to get the xpath for desktop application using winium.desktop driver?

Tags: ui-automation, winium

We used inspect.exe to find the elements. We have tried to find the element with ID,NAME and class name for our desktop application but we found id = "", Name ="" and class name = "Text Box".

We can use class name,but we have two text boxes with the same class name.

So, What are the other possibilities to find element of Windows Desktop application and also how to find the **xpath** for desktop application using winium.desktop driver?

Any help can be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I Know this is little late, but I've used `findelements` in winium to locate all the elements with class name: Text Box and get the first one.

To click on First element with class name as Text box

```
driver.findelements(By.classname("Text Box")).get(0).click();
```